# How to close a popover if anything else is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a popover showing if a onclick is called. What can I do to close the popover if anyhting else is clicked on the page. Someone suggested an on 1 event, but I'm not sure what that is?

Comment: Do you have a overlay behind the popover? Could you post some of your code? That would help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is right in the [popover documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click).  Use `data-trigger="focus"`

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

Comment: when I change to focus it breaks the popover from opening on other button that have the click event.

Answer (score 0):

One event means you need to listen to an action that it is initiated by an user (most of the cases).

When you popover is called you initiate the click event on the popover so the way to cancel the popover (hide it) if to listen to an event in this case you can listen when the user clicks either on the popover or any other element on your page. You can attach an event to your popover or you page with `element.addEventListener('click', function(){//here you can hide your popover})`